# Image Loader Recommendations? Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, picasso, universal-image-loader, image-loading

Recently I've been getting an OutOfMemory Exception in my Xamarin.Android project and the StackTrace says it's because of the ImageViews and ImageButtons I'm using. I'm new to mobile app development and I've never used an Image Loader before. I'm aware of options like Picasso and Universal Image Loader but they both seem to be outdated. Can someone give me some guidance on which one I should use?

I need to be able to reduce the size of my images for both ImageViews and ImageButtons. I'd rather use the ones in my drawable folders but I'd be willing to use a URL too.

Are there any existing samples that could help me get started with the Image Loader you suggest? Or at least a wiki? A dialogue within the comments section of this post would be helpful too.